# How can I convert existing JSFPortlet to JSON API

Tags: jsf-2, portlet, websphere-portal

We have a Portal with huge code base consisting of 100s of JSF-Portlets. Now the requirement is to expose the existing portal as JSON API services to external parties.

One way is to make another presentation layer against each JSFPortlet to resuse the same business and data layer. It will require lot of effort and time.

Another way is if we can play with Portlet & JSF lifecycle and expose the same portlet by overriding serveResource and convert the resourceRequest into actionRequest and call processAction internally. Similarly on return, we can call doView and return the response parameters in form of JSON.

Is this workable?

Comment: the person that told you to expose a jsf portlet as json api has limited knowledge. You expose a service via an api, not a ui component

Comment: Are you planning to complete change the UI of the application from JSF to a different technology which can use these JSF services? Are you moving away from WPS?

Comment: @Kukeltje its not about limited knowledge. Its a business need to deliver the whole web portal as API to external parties. We can follow the standard approach but it will take a lot of development and testing time.

Comment: @Apps No, we will keep the existing portal up along with these JSON APIs. I have done one POC using serveResource and extending JSF-Portlet bridge by IBM to achieve the functionality. But FacesContext is not working as expected. May be I have to use JSF Lifecycle object to execute the phase.

Comment: You can invoke the serveResource method and get the data as JSON. As per my understanding, that doesn't have any relation with the JSF life cycle and none of the components will have access to that data. I don't think it make sense to use the serveResource() method along with JSF components as you will have to do a lot of custom coding on the UI side.

Comment: @Apps, basically when you submit JSF form, it invokes processAction method as per portlet lifecycle, now the JSF-Portlet bridge (provided by IBM) maps the processAction method to JSF lifecycle phases (Restore View, Apply Request Values, Process Validation, Update Model Values, and Invoke Application). And once the action is completed, during render phase doView is called which internally call the render response phase of JSF. Now I have mapped all the data that is required to invoke JSF actionMethod in JSON data structure and pass this JSON to serveResource which is invoking actionMethod.

Answer (score 0):

you would be better off pushing this down to microservices and consuming it wherever is necessary

Comment: Start by putting them in normal services (the 'microservices' concept is overrated if developers do not know basic separation of concerns) ;-) But basically you are right

Comment: @Crosstalk22 We cannot revamp the whole portal to adapt a new architecture as we have short time and budget. And we have to keep both portal and json api up at the same time. What I have done is, I extended the JSF-Portlet bridge by IBM and override the serverResource method to map JSON calls to JSF lifecycle. but facing some issues in FacesContext.

Comment: I understand, but realize at this point you are pretty much, putting lipstick on a pig, JSF lifecycle is dated, as is the serve resource method.  While refactoring usually is a pain, it will make it more consumable over the long hall.  Your real other method is to try and json as a valid content type with your portlet, and have a page the exists that returns json, and then serve it through that page so you can call resource action.  there is the old single portlet url trick you could use as well https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0712_behl/0712_behl.html